# GitLab-CI: run job only when a branch is created

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab

I want to setup gitlab to run a job when a branch when the branch name matches some criteria.
This is my current yml and the job is run when a branch is created that end in '-rc'.
However it also runs if I create a tag ending '-rc'. How can I stop the job running when a tag is created (I have tried exclude - tags).

```
stages:
 - release_to_qa

qa:
    stage: release_to_qa

    when:
        manual

    #except:
     #   - tags

    only:
        - branches
        - /^*-rc$/

    tags:
        - pro1
        - shared
    script:
        echo "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use only & except

```
job:
  # use regexp
  only:
    - /^issue-.*$/
  # use special keyword
  except:
    - branches
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-simplified